# Tornadio2 + Socket.io load testing

Tags: python, websocket, redis, socket.io, tornado

I'm building a real-time application with redis, tornadio2 and socket.io. It works fine on my local machine, but before putting it in production, I would like to do some stress testing.
This way I can know how many clients one instance of tornadio2 websocket connection can handle.

I've searched on Google and I haven't found any ready to use tool to test it.

Should I write this script myself or have I missed something and are there tools for this purposes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use benchmarking tool I used to test node.js socket.io server (and SockJS server).

TornadIO2 will be ~15-20% slower than sockjs-tornado.

Benchmark is here: http://mrjoes.github.com/2011/12/15/sockjs-bench.html

Tool is here: https://github.com/mrjoes/sock-benchmarking

Forgot to mention - it only checks websocket performance. If you plan to have lots of users with polling transport(s), it is good to test these protocols as well.